# ASP.NET - Uploadify works in IE, not in FF (Auth Cookies

Tags: asp.net, cookies, webforms, uploadify

i have a WebForms application, and am trying to use the uploadify jquery library.

It works fine in IE8, but doesn't in FF7, FF10, or FF3. The break point i put in Upload.ashx is not hit.

I did quite the search and found that it has to does with cookies, something like ASPXAUTH. I tried adding it to 'scriptData', but no success.

Any ideas?

Page code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {


        alert($(".hidcook").val());
        // <![CDATA[
        var id = "55";
        var theString = "asdf";

        $('#fileInput').uploadify({
            'uploader': 'uploadify/uploadify.swf',
            'script': 'Upload.ashx',


            'scriptData': { 'id': id, 'foo': theString },
            'cancelImg': 'uploadify/cancel.png',
            'auto': true,
            'multi': true,
            'fileDesc': 'All Files',

            'queueSizeLimit': 90,

            'buttonText': 'Importar Planilha',
            'folder': '/uploads',
            'onAllComplete': function (event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {
            }
        });
    });
   // ]]></script>
```

Upload.ashx:

```
 public class Upload : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState{

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpPostedFile file = context.Request.Files["Filedata"]; //breakpoint

                int id = (Int32.Parse(context.Request["id"]));
                string foo = context.Request["foo"];
                file.SaveAs("C:\\" + id.ToString() + foo + file.FileName);

                context.Response.Write("1");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                context.Response.Write("0");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Try taking the // <![CDATA[ out

Comment: It's commented. Anyway, doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your website content is not public, add to `web.config` authorization access to the Handler.

```
<location path="Upload.ashx">
   <system.web>
     <authorization>
       <allow users="*"/>
     </authorization>
   </system.web>
 </location>
```

There are some differences in how browsers implement file upload through flash component.
IE uses the same session. FF opens a new connection, so the server sees an un-authenticaded user that is trying to access a protected page.

Comment: It works, all i had was to set the proper path. Thanks! Now, care to tell us why? :)

Comment: @WoF_Angel I completed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue using MVC where uploadify didn't post to the controller action.

It was due to an authentication issue. Flash for some reason creates it's own separate cookie to the browser, so if the user has already been authenticated with the browser (ASPXAUTH) cookie, and then the swf file makes a separate request using it's own flash cookie (which has not been authenticated.

Run fiddler to see whats happening, you may find that the server request that the uploadify is making is being redirected to the login.aspx page.

Although I don't know why this would work in just IE?